# How to solve the equations of the type $\sin a + \sin b = \sin x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I came across a question in my book that's like this:

$$\sin20 + \sin40 = \sin x $$

I don't know if the values of the $a$ and $b$ make a difference (or in this case, the fact that $b = 2a$) but I'd like to know how would one solve this kind of equation.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about $\sin^{-1}(x)$ or not yet ?

Comment: Aren't you satisfied by $x=\arcsin(\sin 20+\sin 40)$? Notice that there are trivial issues if the LHS is greater than one or less than minus one.

Comment: Well, I can see that $x = \arcsin({\sin20 + \sin40})$ but then I'd like to know what is $\arcsin({\sin20 + \sin40})$? Because in this case it seems that you actually get an integer solution

Comment: @MertcanEkiz, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this special case, you can use sum of sine:
$$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}$$

So if your $20,40$ are in degrees,
$$\sin 20^\circ +\sin 40^\circ=2\sin 30^\circ\cos 10^\circ=\cos 10^\circ$$

If $\cos 10^\circ=\sin x$, then $x=80^\circ$ or $100^\circ$, or plus integer multiples of $360^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: Anyone can explain why the downvote?

Comment: it must be degree

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I said "in degrees".

Comment: but the $\circ$ is missing

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: OK, changed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x = \sin 20^\circ + \sin 40^\circ$$
$$\sin x = \sin 20^\circ + \sin (60^\circ-20^\circ)$$
Can you take it from here?